# Facebook Login without FBSDKLoginButton in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am trying to add facebook login for my app. I am using the FBSDKLoginButton which comes with its own button and once you login it turns to logout. I don't want all that. I just need to add my own button a view. And in that button's @IBAction I want the facebook login to take place. The code which I am now using is

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
        }
        else
        {
            let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            self.view.addSubview(loginView)
            loginView.center = self.view.center
            loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
            loginView.delegate = self
        }

    }


    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        println("User Logged In")

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            // Handle cancellations
        }
        else {
            returnUserData()
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
            {
                // Do work
            }
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        println("User Logged Out")
    }

    func returnUserData()
    {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                println("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                println("fetched user: \(result)")
                let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                println("User Name is: \(userName)")
                let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
                println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
            }
        })

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

How do I customise this and achieve what I need. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FBSDKLoginManager can be used if FB Login is handled via custom button.

For more info, your can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32309831/1673045).

Answer (score 9):

You might want to check the latest FacebookSDK, here's what i have:

```
@IBAction func connectWithFacebook(){

    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        return
    }

    let login:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    login.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        }else if(result.isCancelled){
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        }else{
             //Handle login success
        }
    })
}
```

Otherwise with the older SDK you can do the following:

- Add the FBSDKLoginButton to your view and set it invisible
- Add your custom button
- On your custom button IBAction perform a click on the FBSDKLoginButton with the method `sendActionsForControlEvents`

Comment: I think you can just tell me how to do the last point you mentioned.  IBAction perform a click on the FBSDKLoginButton with the method sendActionsForControlEvents. Other stuff which you had put is not gonna help to the question which I asked and the reply from you either.

Comment: Still it would be best to get FacebookSDK 4, which version of the sdk are you currently using ? I'm not sure FacebookLoginButton should be used for that, i had a FacebookLoginView, but i'm not sure it's available for you.

Comment: I am using the latest version. I mean I downloaded the SDK just now.

Comment: Then, if you want custom UI, you should forget about FBSDKLoginButton. Here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3 check the 'Using Custom Login UIs' paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Set current access is nil.

> This calls [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil] and
>   [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil].

FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)

For Facebook logout.